# Multiple Polymer iron-scroll-threshold to load more data AND detect element visibility

Tags: javascript, polymer

I have a custom element which displays a list of messages.

There is one `iron-scroll-threshold` wrapping an `iron-list` which has the task of loading new messages as the user scrolls down:

```
<div class="container">
    <iron-scroll-threshold id="t" lower-threshold="500" on-lower-threshold="_ld">
        <iron-list items="[[messages]]" as="m" scroll-target="t">
            <template>
                <div>
                    <!-- Messages markup here -->
                </div>
            </template>
        </iron-list>
    </iron-scroll-threshold>
</div>
```

That works fine.

I need a second kind of scroll-listener to mark messages as read as soon as they become visible (scrolled into the viewport). This should happen independently from loading new messages.

Is it possible to add a second `iron-scroll-threshold` for that purpose or is there a better way to achieve that?

**Edit**

I have tried to put an `on-content-scroll` on several elements but the event never get's fired.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's possible by not wrapping the `iron-list` with the `iron-scroll-threshold` element & using the scroll-target attribute of iron-scroll-threshold. So something like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <iron-scroll-threshold id="t1" scroll-target="list" lower-threshold="500" on-lower-threshold="_ld"/>
    <iron-scroll-threshold id="t2" scroll-target="list" lower-threshold="500" on-lower-threshold="_ld2"/>
    <iron-list id="list" items="[[messages]]" as="m">
        <template>
            <div>
                <!-- Messages markup here -->
            </div>
        </template>
    </iron-list>
</div>
```

I'm not 100% that there won't be some kind of unexpected interaction having multiple iron-scroll-thresholds...but I don't see anything with a quick look through the source.

Comment: Thanks, that looks good. I tried it :) Both _ld and _ld2 are fired when the element is initially loaded (note that the initial loading is also the case if only one iron-scroll-threshold is present), which is strange anyway. Then when I scroll, only _ld is fired, and _ld2 never.

Comment: Sounds like there may be some interactions happening that I didn't expect when scanning the code. I can't investigate further right now (eg no time) but seems like a reasonable bug to file on the iron-scroll-threshold repo - https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-scroll-threshold

Answer (score 0):

You know also not sure the above would be the best approach anyways for what you want to do... Another approach might be something using [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect), along the lines of [How to tell if a DOM element is visible in the current viewport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport/7557433#7557433), but since the context here involves iron-list, which is a virtual list, this is not straightforward.

iron-list list does have two getters which appear to be public named firstVisibleIndex & lastVisibleIndex so a rough thought is that you could check if your messages are within that range occasionally as the user scrolls.